# Reuse Connection with HttpWebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, httprequest

I need to make a POST request using .Net.

I can authenticate by GET, and so I’m trying to make a POST request on the same connection to keep my authentication.

The problem is I get a 401 Not Authenticated exception, which implies the connection hasn’t been reused.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("my-server");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");

request.GetResponse().Close();  // Works fine

// Now the request I want to make...

request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("my-server");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");

request.Method = "post";

string postData = "param1=1&param2=2";
byte[] data = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    stream.Close();
    request.GetResponse().Close();      // This line gets a 401 Not Authorized error.
}
```

EDIT: There has been some suggestions that I need to transfer cookies. The following doesn’t work either:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("my-server");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
foreach (Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
{
    cookieContainer.Add(cookie);
}

response.Close();

// Now the request I want to make...

request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("my-server");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

request.Method = "post";

string postData = "param1=1&param2=2";
byte[] data = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    request.GetResponse().Close();      // This line gets a 401 Not Authorized error.
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reuse a HttpWebRequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179626/reuse-a-httpwebrequest)

Comment: The answer there was to close the response. I’ve done this on the third line.

Comment: the "using" will automatically close the stream, so perhaps removing "stream.Close();" will help.

Comment: Is it the same connection if you create a new `WebRequest`?

Comment: @climbage I cannot set the content on an existing one.

Comment: @rontornambe Doesn’t have any effect.

Answer (score 6):

The reason you don't stay logged in is because you don't give the HttpWebRequest a CookieContainer to keep the session id in.

See the following to StackOverflow Q&A's for your possible solution:

[C# keep session id over httpwebrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453560/c-sharp-keep-session-id-over-httpwebrequest)

[Multiple WebRequest in same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787857/multiple-webrequest-in-same-session)

I hope this helped.

Comment: Also, the HttpWebResponse does not contain any cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Any idea how the authentication is managed on the other end?  IE. If it sets a cookie, then you need to make sure you account for that, see this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), and specifically this note:

> Note
>
> For security reasons, cookies are disabled by default. If you want to use cookies, use the CookieContainer property to enable cookies.