# JSON data from website

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm currently using VB .NET 2010.  I'm trying to read data from a JSON request from the website https://tradingpost-live.ncplatform.net/ws/search.json  (Guild Wars 2 site).

The website requires you to be logged in via the forums.  Even having this in my vb app via a webbrowser object, I am still receiving a 401 Unauthorized error.  I assume some sort of cookie is needed???

The biggest issue I have is trying to run the larger search @ https://tradingpost-live.ncplatform.net/ws/search.json?text=&levelmin=0&levelmax=80&count=0

This gives me the error "Unable to download search.json from tradingpost-live.ncplatform.net.  Unable to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later.

By using Firefox, I can login and view each of these 2 sites without any issues.  Any chance I can get a pointer in the right direction? So far I've installed JSON.NET but have no clue how to use it or if I should be doing something else...... almost midnight and my brain is fried!

Comment: If you look at the documentation on the [Guild Wars forums](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/community/api/Guide-to-the-Black-Lion-Trading-Co-API) you should be able to get it working.

Comment: It would be good to add a code sample. This can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/9025140/669527