# Session cookies - CookieContainer on stack rather than heap causing issue

Tags: session, cookies, httpwebrequest, cookiecontainer

I've had a look here 
[C# WebRequest using Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158448/c-sharp-webrequest-using-cookies)
[Multiple WebRequest in same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787857/multiple-webrequest-in-same-session)
[Reuse Connection with HttpWebRequest in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025075/reuse-connection-with-httpwebrequest-in-c-sharp)
[C# keep session id over httpwebrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453560/c-sharp-keep-session-id-over-httpwebrequest)

And that's what I'm doing except I wish to store my CookieContainer as a member (named session_cookie) in my class called connector. My problem is that if I use a temporary object in my code then the cookies work fine:

```
CookieContainer t = new CookieContainer();
HTTPReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(scriptURL);
HTTPReq.CookieContainer = t;
```

But if I use

```
HTTPReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(scriptURL);
HTTPReq.CookieContainer = session_cookie;
```

Then it doesn't work! I cannot figure out why

Here is the connector class code:

```
public class Connector
{
    public CookieContainer session_cookie;
    private string session_id;
    private HttpWebRequest HTTPReq;
    private HttpWebResponse Response;

    //Session oriented connection
    public string serverRequest(string scriptURL, string payLoad) 
    {
        try
        {
            HTTPReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(scriptURL);
        HTTPReq.CookieContainer = session_cookie;
        HTTPReq.Method = "POST";                      

        //Data arguments
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payLoad);
        HTTPReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        HTTPReq.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        //Get the stream to write into
        Stream dataStream = HTTPReq.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        Response = (HttpWebResponse)HTTPReq.GetResponse();

        Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);  // Western latin alphabet (windows default)

        //Get the repsonse from the server
        StreamReader ResponseStream = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream(), enc);

        string response = ResponseStream.ReadToEnd().Trim();

        Response.Close();
        ResponseStream.Close();
        return response;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return null;
        }
    }    
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a constructor for your Connector class which needs to initialize your CookieContainer property. You should also use a CookieCollection for capturing the cookies from the response and sending to the next request. Something like this should work:

```
public class Connector
{
    public CookieContainer session_cookie;
    private CookieCollection cookies;
    private string session_id;
    private HttpWebRequest HTTPReq;
    private HttpWebResponse Response;

    public Connector()
    {
        session_cookie = new CookieContainer();
        cookies = new CookieCollection();
    }

    //Session oriented connection
    public string serverRequest(string scriptURL, string payLoad) 
    {
        try
        {
        HTTPReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(scriptURL);
        HTTPReq.CookieContainer = session_cookie;
            HTTPReq.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        HTTPReq.Method = "POST";                      

        //Data arguments
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payLoad);
        HTTPReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        HTTPReq.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        //Get the stream to write into
        Stream dataStream = HTTPReq.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        Response = (HttpWebResponse)HTTPReq.GetResponse();
            cookies = Response.Cookies; // capture cookies from response for next request

        Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);  // Western latin alphabet (windows default)

        //Get the repsonse from the server
        StreamReader ResponseStream = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream(), enc);

        string response = ResponseStream.ReadToEnd().Trim();

        Response.Close();
        ResponseStream.Close();
        return response;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return null;
        }
    }

}
```