# Testing fairness of a server in C#

Tags: c#, networking

I have a server that is already set up and running. I would like to test it if it is fair for `n` users and limits each of them equally. For this I would like to establish `n` connections to the server (it's simple entering a website) and test the response time to each of them. The problem is - I don't want to use `n` computers for this task. How to do this with only one computer? Should I emulate IP addresses of the senders (those who send the `HttpRequest`)?

Comment: Does it matter of all the requests come from the same IP? It should not affect session isolation

Comment: Make sure each HttpWebRequest has its own cookie collection, E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787857/multiple-webrequest-in-same-session

Comment: You could try apache bench, http://www.petefreitag.com/item/689.cfm, although the results of that can vary depending on your computer and connection etc.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use multi threading c# . library threading.
you can create n requests. but the problem is thet when you measure te time ( you can use stopwatch object c#)  of response the client can be overloaded and could not measure exact time